# How to read in and display text in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am currently working to automate some basic data analysis in R, then create an R Markdown document that includes all of the results.  One thing I'm trying to do is take a text file that contains an experimental design and a paragraph or two of text explaining an experiment and render that text in the R Markdown document.  Is there a good way to transfer text from text files to R Markdown documents?

Currently, I have tried to read the text file into a dataframe, then print the rows of the frame that include the text to the Markdown document.  However, the text is then cut off at the page margin of the Markdown document, and only prints the first line.  However, when I attempt to use cat() on the saved text variable, it prints to the console.

Answer (score 0):

If your external text file is called `text_to_print.txt` (can also be e.g., `.Rmd`), one way to do this is to put the following inside your main Rmarkdown file as a code block:

````
```{r, child = "text_to_print.txt", results = "asis"}
```
````

If `text_to_print.txt` lives in another directory you will need to adjust the file passed to `child`.

More info on "Child documents" here: [16.4 Child documents](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html).

Comment: @Cserody Happy to hear it. Please accept this answer to mark the thread closed.